# How to override the CSS properties of AntDesign pro?

Tags: css, reactjs, ant-design-pro

I want to override the CSS properties of antDesign pro in my project. Can you please help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include your css file under the antDesign css/cdn ,
use **!important**  in your css

```
p {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```